# How does ActiveRecord pretty format record instances in console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given that I have a **user** model, calling `User.new` in console returns a User object along with anattributes list rather than a list of instance variables, which is the ruby default when you call `ClassName.new`

My question is how is where does this override take place? How can we control what is returned when we call an instance object?

Comment: well no, it will return the object created by `new`. That hasn't changed.

Comment: @sevenseacat indeed it returns a User object. But how does rail tell it to return it with a list of attributes?

Answer (score 1):

The output is overridden by overriding `inspect`. e.g see

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L418

and

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L191